# TemporaryDirectory() throws an attribute error when program runs

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am attempting to create a temporary directory using `with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as directory:`

I have imported tempfile

When I run the program I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "batch.py", line 79, in <module>
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as directory:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TemporaryDirectory'
```

I am running python 3.8

The program will run successfully if run with the debugger but when I run it without the debugger I get this error.

Full Code:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as directory:
   for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
      if subdir != rootdir and subdir != fDestination and subdir != meDir 
      and subdir != fileDestination and subdir != zdir:
         shutil.move(subdir, directory)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Could you post the entire code, or if you can't, a smaller sample that shows the error?

Comment: Small sample code that shows the error has been posted.